# How to change the position of images cloned with a script?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to clone an image and change the position of the cloned copy. I am cloning with the following script that follows an image defined in the document:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('autumn1');
    var img = new Image(); 
    img.src = 'autumn-leaves-hd-png--3101.png';
    div.appendChild(img);

    img.height = window.innerHeight / 6;
    img.width = window.innerWidth / 6;

    function cloneImg() {
        div.appendChild(img.cloneNode(true));
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        cloneImg();
        img.forEach(img.X = Math.random());
    }
}
```

How can I introduce changing of position of the cloned image, in the script above?

Comment: Two things: 1) your script will generate a runtime error, by the way -- there is no `forEach` method on an `Image` or `HTMLImageElement` object, and 2) you "clone" the image already with the first four lines of your "load" event handler function -- you don't mention that in your question, and then use `cloneImg` in the loop -- why do you clone using two different methods, resulting in five clones in total?

Comment: yep, I got your point. I'll improve it too. but my question is how to change the position of these cloned images. that's the part where I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the image element in the function.

Please see snippet below :

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('autumn1');
    var img = new Image(); 
    img.src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bef07ce752c0e44449f4ec791d752871?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1';
    div.appendChild(img);

    img.height = window.innerHeight / 6;
    img.width = window.innerWidth / 6;

    function cloneImg() {
        return div.appendChild(img.cloneNode(true));
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        let clone = cloneImg();
        let random = Math.random()*75;
        clone.style.position = 'absolute'
        clone.style.left =  random + "%";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="autumn1"></div>
```